# Zip files with same name on Windows using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

Let's say we have:

- somedir

  - file1.eps
  - file1.jpg
  - file2.eps
  - file2.jpg

What I want to do is, to get zips of every eps, jpg couple with the same names like:

- somedir

  - file1.zip
  - file2.zip

I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with help of WinRAR:

```
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
forfiles /s /m *.jpg /C "cmd /c winrar.exe a -afzip "@fname.zip" "@fname.eps" "@fname.jpg"
pause
```

Comment: Why are you using the `forfiles` command rather than the standard `for` command, which is much faster?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example with windows native zip.exe. It looks for only *.eps files inside of current directory (because you have pair of files with the same name and different extensions), then it extracts filename, adds .eps and .jpg extensions and zip them with same name.

```
for /r %i in (*.eps) do zip %~ni.zip %~ni.eps %~ni.jpg
```

If you write inside of script then white with %%i

```
for /r %%i in (*.eps) do zip %%~ni.zip %%~ni.eps %%~ni.jpg
```